# Quad XOR IC query 4030/4507

Tags: integrated-circuit

My question is two fold.

Looking at the Wikipedia page for the [List of 4000-series integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4000-series_integrated_circuits), it states that the 4030 has been superseded by the 4070.  Looking at various links<sup>1</sup> it seems to be due to (from CMOS Cookbook, 1977, p.97):

> Early versions of this device have a very low input impedance and
>   behave erratically in pulse circuits.
>
> Use the 4070 or equivalent 4507 instead.

- Would that still be the case, for the few 4030 IC's that are still available on eBay<sup>2</sup>, or would those issues have been "ironed out" by now (or are they decades old stock)?

Also, the mention of the 4570, which is not listed on the wikipedia page. When I try to find it on ebay, I find only this: [N°1 - CD4507CP - MC1407UB - MOT - DUAL COMPLEMENTARY PAIR PLUS INVERTER](http://www.ebay.com/itm/N-1-CD4507CP-MC1407UB-MOT-DUAL-COMPLEMENTARY-PAIR-PLUS-INVERTER/302002108994), which does not sound right at all<sup>3</sup>. Google seems to only turn up a Cisco switch.

- So, what happened to the CD4507 and why is that even less common than the CD4030?

---

<sup>1</sup> These links:

- [logic gate chips](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/logic-gate-chips.3650/) mentions the 4507
- [4030 vs 4070?](http://www.science-bbs.com/66-electronics-basics/8ef7cab1a1efe51a.htm) has a number of reasons why the 4030 was discontinued
- [momentary electronic switching](https://www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/index.php?PHPSESSID=0n1l2fa1523mkbbhrprnft32e7&topic=36658.msg259838#msg259838) only states “CD4030 is generally rated for lower Vcc than CD4070.”

<sup>2</sup> Such as [2 x CD4030BE CD4030 4030 IC Quad Exclusive OR Gate](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-x-CD4030BE-CD4030-4030-IC-Quad-Exclusive-OR-Gate/250839957094)

<sup>3</sup> Obviously eBay is not an authority on such matters and the item is possibly mis-advertised

Comment: You should use datasheets to collect trustworthy information, not the forum posts and ebay seller descriptions. Did you try looking for datasheets for these devices? There're a number of sites out there, and I am sure manufacturers do still have some info on their sites. This skill of finding relevant info is anyway very important to learn.

Comment: Obviously the differences between 4030 and 4070 are such that a new product number was needed. Also "fixing" the 4030 could result in products (using the 4030) not working as the fixed 4030 and old 4030 behave differently. No IC manufacturer want to explain that to a customer. Saying: 4030 has issues, use 4070 instead is much more clear and raises less questions. So 4030 will be the old 4030 including the issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. I doubt it has changed for the available stock. You should expect the same (bad) performance from these parts.
2. It was replaced by the MC14070B. Probably fixing all these issues and complying with ROHS along the way.