# Switching between sequence different sequence lengths in pseudorandom number generating

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, shift-register, random-number

I was reading *[Use Readily Available Components to Generate Pseudo-Random Binary Sequences and White Noise](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2018/mar/use-readily-available-components-generate-binary-sequences-white-noise)*, by Art Pini, to understand generating pseudorandom numbers.

I understand that broadly speaking, you need a shift register and an XOR gate.

I was wondering if there's a way to design a pseudorandom bit generator that switches between different sequence lengths (between 11 bit and 7 bit random number generation) **with the change of a single digital input value** (high <-> low for example).

Comment: Probably. Why not go try to design one?

Comment: As you don't specify what that single digital input value is connected to, then trivially yes, if it controls a multiplexer that selects the appropriate XORed feedback term from a long generator. You may find a solution with fewer gates depending on what specific polynomials you use. Remember that tables of taps for m-sequences only show one particular configuration, the number of valid configurations grows quickly as N grows, so there's more choice than it appears at first. Note that you *always* need a feedback term from the Nth latch when generating a 2^N-1 length sequence.

Comment: If you can get hold of one, use a CD4006 along with a CD4070 XOR package. Search for "CD4006 LFSR" for schematics, you can easily modify one of those schematics to give your differing sequence lengths. It should also be noted that the 4030 referenced in that article is obsolete and has been replaced by the 4070, see [Quad XOR IC query 4030/4507](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392175/quad-xor-ic-query-4030-4507)